# Progressbar not working on scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a module where when a user reads PDF files in a container, the progress bar shows the effect based on scroll bar of that container. Somehow there is no effect on the progress bar when user scrolls down or up.

Here is my html part for it,

```
 <div id="viewer" class="pdf-viewer" oncontextmenu="return false" data-url="../sadmin/studyMaterial/<?php echo $db->idToField("tbl_studymaterials", "file_ppt", $chapterId) ; ?>"></div>
 <span><progress id="progressbar" value="0" max="100" width="100%"></progress></span>
```

And here goes my JS for scroll,

```
<script>
var viewer = document.getElementById('viewer');
viewer.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
      var s = this.scrollTop,
      d = this.scrollHeight,
      c = this.clientHeight,
      position = (s / (d - c)) * 100;     
     document.getElementById('progressbar').value = position;
});
</script>
```

I have tried a lot and looked many times but seems there is no success on this part. Can someone suggest where is the missing part and why its not showing the desired results. I am a novice in JS and struggling on this to manage . Any advice or help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code works just fine =) https://codepen.io/RudManusachi/pen/VzENXE
maybe something wrong with CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working example:

```js
var viewer = document.getElementById('viewer');

    viewer.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
        var s = this.scrollTop,
        d = this.scrollHeight,
        c = this.clientHeight,
        position = (s / (d - c)) * 100;
        document.getElementById('progressbar').value = position;
    });
```

```css
 #viewer{
      height: 100px;
      width: 500px;
      border: 1px solid #565656;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      overflow-y: auto;
    }
```

```html
<div id = "viewer" class = "pdf-viewer" oncontextmenu="return false" data-url="../sadmin/studyMaterial/<?php echo $db->idToField('tbl_studymaterials', 'file_ppt', $chapterId); ?>">
  aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaa aaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa 
</div>
<span>
  <progress id="progressbar" value="0" max="100" width="100%">
  </progress>
</span>
```

Comment: Thanks for the valuable time. I am unable to find this particular #viewer in css. Can I get this using the class? What changes do I need to make @adda82

Comment: The trick is to add fixed height and overflow : hidden to the scroll element. In my example that is the #viewer.  I guess you will have the pdf inside this element. Then you will see the scroll and you already have the javascript function that triggers on scroll. Hope that helps.

Comment: No success yet @adda82

Comment: I have edited the code above. I left your html code same as you provided, I found one mistake in php code, you have used double quotations instead single on variables "tbl_studymaterials", "file_ppt". Try now to use my code and see if it works. Do not forget to include the css code for #viewer.

Comment: Thanks alot for your precious time mate. But there is some glitches actually into the CSS that I am unable to find. Thanks again for your concern. I tried your solution but therein the content is not shown . And yes the code for viewer when applied shows no scroll bar. So can it be given explicitly?

Comment: Are you getting any content into the #viewer div from PHP ?

Comment: No, when changed the viewer style(as given by you), it appears blank @adda82 Somewhere 'pdf-viewer' and 'viewer' are internally connected and being into PHP makes to tough for me obtain actual results.

Comment: Yea in order scroll to work you will have to have content inside. The content should  overflow the #viewer div and scroll should then show, this is how it works.

Comment: Somehow I can see my content inside the #viewer mate. But still the problem persists.

Comment: var viewer = document.getElementById('viewer');

    viewer.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
        var s = this.scrollTop,
        d = this.scrollHeight,
        c = this.clientHeight,
        position = (s / (d - c)) * 100;
        document.getElementById('progressbar').value = position;
    }); This requires anything more to be added? Like currently I have this in <script></script> . Anything to change?

Comment: No I just tried it again and the script is working perfect when I add the css provided in my answer.

Comment: Maybe it would help if you can go to inspect element and copy your html with content and everything so I can see exactly what your html looks like.

Comment: I went for inspect element but the copying of html is not active in there. Is there any other way?

Comment: Can I have your email or something. I can post it there at.

Comment: Right click on target element and choose 'edit as html' then you will be able to copy.

Comment: Just shot a mail. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is, that you add the scroll listener to viewer, and the viewer has no scroll bar, what it means that the event isn't fired in that div, it's fired on the window or some parent container element, because if I add this style to the viewer, the code snipet works fine

```
#viewer {
  height: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

So I suggest for you, to search the item what has the scroll bar and add the event listener to that element (maybe you need to rewrite the calculations but thats a solution), or you give your div a height.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable time. I am unable to find this particular #viewer in css. Can I get this using the class? What changes do I need to make

Comment: I don't really know how your css works, because the main thing is that you need to make your div scroll-able. but you can add what I wrote to your css file, and change the height accordingly to your design